# How to find WheelChair accessible Tube Stations in UK?

Tags: uk, trains, public-transport, uk-residents

I am a bit confused about the tube map with accessibility signs.The blue symbol shows step-free access from "street to train" and the white symbol shows step-free access from "street to platform". But it only shows ONE SYMBOL per station, what if a station has both privileges? I mean a station can have both step-free access from street to train and step-free access from street to platform, how do I recognize these stations?

> [image: A map with the symbol]

Can anyone interpret the exact meaning of these symbols?

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Would have thought it’s pretty obvious that one (street to train) is inclusive of the the other (street to platform) by definition.

Comment: @Darren - you'd think, but there's been one heck of a lot of discussion since… showing what is obvious to some takes 40 paragraphs of explanation for others ;))

Comment: @Darren by what definition its obvious? there is a station which has level access but not lift (street to platform), so much for the definition! New tourists/visitors are not well aware of this.

Comment: If a station has lift free access to the train, then it must have step free access to every intermediate  location, including the platform. That’s what I mean “by defintion”.

Comment: Also, step free access to the platform doesn’t preclude the station from having a lift, which is what I think your comment is saying. In fact, it’s almost certainly the case that it *does* have a lift.

Comment: There are also stations when their is level access to change between some trains but not into/out the stations.  https://tfl.gov.uk/maps_/using-tfl-go is likely the best option, the paper access guild is now very out of date.

Comment: Just a correction to my comment above “If a station has step-free access…”

Comment: @IanRingrose thats exactly what I meant, thats why TFL should have made it clear. A newcomer/visitor doesn't presuppose all these. At first sight of the map, a visitor is not supposed to know that Blue Symbol indicates both "street to platform and train".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Transport for London tell us](https://tfl.gov.uk/transport-accessibility/wheelchair-access-and-avoiding-stairs):

> Some step-free stations still have a gap and step between the platform and the train. The Tube map shows which Underground, Overground and DLR stations are step-free. The blue symbol shows step-free access from street to train and the white symbol shows step-free access from street to platform.

And

> ### Level access at platforms
>
> An increasing number of our platforms give step-free access onto trains.
>
> This is provided in three ways:
>
> #### Level access along the whole platform
>
> This is available on newly built services such as the Jubilee line east of Westminster, the whole DLR network and new stations on London Overground.
>
> #### Level access along part of the platform (platform humps)
>
> We are increasingly using these at stations. Look out for the signs for these on platforms and for information about where to find them in Journey Planner.
>
> #### Manual boarding ramps
>
> At some stations staff will deploy manual boarding ramps to help you get on and off. This service is available at many Overground, Elizabeth line and Tube stations. To use manual boarding ramps, ask for help from staff.
>
> There are some steps that station staff will follow to deploy ramps:
>
> - A member of staff will place a ramp to help you get from the platform into the train
> - If a ramp is needed at your interchange or alighting station, they will contact the station to make sure a member of staff is waiting to meet you to help you get off the train

So basically:

- The white on blue sign (step-free access from the street to the train) means you can get from the street to the platform step-free **and** one of the first two situations (level access along all or part of the platform), so step-free access from the platform to the train, and you don’t need any help).
- The blue on white one (step-free access from the street to the platform) means you can get to/from the platform by yourself, but you need help from staff to get onto the train (or alight from it), as they will have to deploy a manual ramp.

Make sure that if you board at a station with step-free access to the train but alight at a station with only step-free access to the platform, you notify staff in advance so someone will be there to help you get off the train with a ramp. You will probably be provided instructions on where in the train you should board.

The page linked to above as a lot more information and links to even more.

Comment: thank u, so in short, street to train means level access and street to platform means Lift, am I right? u also said "street to platform" symbol also indicates "street to train" but not vice versa. am I right?

Comment: The second sentence above is completely wrong; "street to train" implies "street to platform", because it's "street to platform to train"; but "street  to platform" emphatically doesn't imply "street to train".  The first is also wrong; "street to train" often involves lifts, just as "street to platform" does.

Comment: @MadHatter Thnk u, I just wonder why "street to train" implies "street to platform", cant it be that a station has level access but not lift? why does one always follow the other? Why does a station with level access always have a Lift?

Comment: I also wonder why these things are not clarified in ANYWHERE (TFL), its pretty fuzzy and confusing. Its not something we can just assume, esp. a newcomer/visitor. Is there any way I can contact TFL and recommend a rephrasing/clarification on their site?

Comment: @Tanvir street to platform means you can get to the platform without any steps. It might be via the usage of lifts, ramps, or (quite unlikely for the Tube), just direct level access. Street to train means street to platform **and** step free access from platform to train, which means you can get on the train without any help, while in the first case you do need help.

Comment: In addition to the page linked above, there is a detailed [Step-free Tube Guide](https://content.tfl.gov.uk/step-free-tube-guide-map.pdf) with instructions and explanations. You can also use the TfL journey planner or app and specify you want step-free journeys to the train.

Comment: It is worth noting that most of the Tube network was build over a century ago, when accessibility concerns were not the same. By default, older parts of the Tube don’t have any form of step free access. Recent extensions are fully step-free, and for older ones, retrofits have been made. Step-free access from platform to train is just plain impossible in any of those older stations without works, so they don’t add it unless it is actually useful and you can get from the street to the platform step-free.

Comment: Usually when they add lifts etc. they will also add step-free access to the train by raison part or all of the platform, but on some cases it’s just plain impossible: when the station is on a curve, while they could raise the platform, a large gap may remain. In those cases manual ramps are used.

Comment: @jcaron thanks a lot, if u look at the "Step-free Tube Guide", u will find that it only shows the Level Access, not the Lift. There is a legend/key for lift in the map, but not implemented/shown in the map. I appreciate the otherr replies. TFL must clarify this on their website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145196/discussion-between-jcaron-and-tanvir).

Answer (score 9):

If a station has step-free access all the way to the train it automatically has step-free access to the platform.

So the symbol for step-free access to the train does also include the other symbol.

Comment: so "step-free access to the train" means BOTH? r u certain about that? 
if SO, why doesn't the authority (TFL) clarify that?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, step-free access from “street to platform” means there is Lift/street ramp etc to access/exit the station and step-free access from “street to train” means the gap between platform and train (level access).

Comment: I'm not sure it really needs clarifying. If it says street to train, you have to be able to get to the platform to get to the train, so one is automatically a sub-set of the other. Note 'to train' isn't necessarily the entire train - many just have one raised section for roll-on/roll/off, usually on the straightest bit of the platform, the rest is the same step/gap as usual.

Comment: @Tetsujin cant it be that a station has level access but not lift? why does one always follow the other? Why does a station with level access always have a Lift? just curious!

Comment: @Tanvir what would be the usefulness of such a station in terms of accessibility?

Comment: Well, 1) you're assuming there's no such thing as a ramp & that all tube stations are underground 2) what would be the point, if you could get off the train but not out of the station? Those are marked separately, where you can transfer but not get out.

Comment: @jcaron: There are times when it may be useful to have step-free train-to-platform-to-train access without needing step-free street access, though planning trips would require a specific list of which platforms are connected in step-free fashion.  Some stations will have platform between two tracks going opposite directions, and some will have tracks between platforms, requiring use of a pedestrian flyover.

Comment: @supercat - this is all on the detailed map linked in comments above. There are some platforms/lines with platforms on the same level, but they're quite rare - each line has to generally go under or over all others it may cross without climbing steep hills - because of this, each line is at a different depth.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Lines that cross each other without overlap would be at different levels, but certainly subsurface trains have many lines that share the same platforms, and even some deep tunnel platforms serve trains that go to different destinations.

Comment: @supercat - sure, but this was not the issue raised by the OP; only later. As already mentioned, there's a map of these specific inter-line transfers. You can't generalise.

Comment: thanks everyone for the clarification.